# Read large ndef record with problem on iOS 15.3 (pn7150, ndef)

Tags: android, ios, nfc, ndef

I try to read large ndef record from pn7150.

Configuration:

- pn7150 working in card emulation mode (type 4 tag, example from nxp nfc library)
- large text record build by ndef lib in python with 350 bytes of data (simple lorem ipsum)
- Android phone (xiaomi redmi 9, android 10) and nfc tools app
- iphone se 2nd generation with iOS 15.3 and nfc tools app

On Android:

```
1. Send Read command asking for a Ndef record size ( 0x00 0xb0 0x00 0x00 0x02)
2. Next command is a read record with offset 2 (0x00 0xb0 0x00 0x02 0xff )
3 then when I send 255 bytes I get another command from phone ( 0x60 0x06 0x03 0x01 0x00 0x01) it looks like NCI command -> CORE_CONN_CREDITS_NTF
4. then Phone sends read command (0x00 0xb0 0x00 0xff 0x6b) with offset 0xff
5. and I send the rest of ndef record.
6. I can see whole record in application
```

On iPhone:

```
1. Send Read command asking for a Ndef record size ( 0x00 0xb0 0x00 0x00 0x02)
2. Next command is a read record (0x00 0xb0 0x00 0x00 0xff)
3 then when I send 255 bytes I get another command from phone ( 0x60 0x06 0x03 0x01 0x00 0x01) it looks like NCI command -> CORE_CONN_CREDITS_NTF
4. I don't receive next read command to send rest of the ndef record.
5. I can't see any record in application
```

Do you have an idea what is appropriate way to receive large ndef record on iOS?

I can put here whole communication with NCI command if it's necessary :)

Comment: Have you set the Ndef Record Type to be a "Short Record", if yes then the record can only be 255 bytes long. It might be worth posting the first 6 bytes of the Record

Comment: I used python ndef lib, but I checked generated hex and it's a "Normal Record" with 4 bytes size of payload length